# Preserve arguments in uri builder

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-6.1.x, realurl, uribuilder

Let's say that I have a page with URI:

```
 http://mydomain.loc/index.php?id=123&by=name&dir=desc
```

and need to add/update/remove some other param (let's name it *offset*) to it, so after all it will be:

```
 http://mydomain.loc/index.php?id=123&by=name&dir=desc&offset=321
```

Unfortunately when building new link with `uriBuilder` like this

```
$uriBuilder = $this->uriBuilder;
$uri = $uriBuilder->setArguments(array('offset' => 321))->build();
```

I get only `index.php?id=123&offset=321` (no `by` and `dir` arguments anymore...)

How can I force `uriBuilder` to preserve these arguments ? (manual rewriting arguments by `GeneralUtility::_GP(*)` isn't possible, cause they are theoretically *unknown*)

Also `$_GET` array isn't good as I'm wrking with RealURL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The uriBuilder has a `setAddQueryString` method, that does exactly what you want. It merges the current query string into the arguments:

```
$uri = $this->uriBuilder->setArguments(array('offset' => 321))->setAddQueryString(TRUE)->build();
```

As a reference here is the method copied from the actual class out of the TYPO3 core:

```
/**
 * If set, the current query parameters will be merged with $this->arguments. Defaults to FALSE.
 *
 * @param boolean $addQueryString
 * @return \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Web\Routing\UriBuilder the current UriBuilder to allow method chaining
 * @api
 * @see TSref/typolink.addQueryString
 */
public function setAddQueryString($addQueryString) {
    $this->addQueryString = (boolean) $addQueryString;
    return $this;
}
```